# Why can we call a class method before it's defined, but can't do the same with free functions?

Tags: c++

Why is this valid?

```cpp
struct A {
    void caller() {
        callee();
    }
 
    void callee() {
        std::cout << "callee" << std::endl;
    }
};

// A a; a.caller(); Outputs "callee"
```

But this is not?

```cpp
void callerFree() {
    calleeFree();
}
 
void calleeFree() {
    std::cout << "calleeFree" << std::endl;
}
```

In my point of view, the `class`/`struct` is just a syntax-sugar for the same functions callable with an argument of some data chunk (object) on which it operates.

What is the difference between those?

Comment: Is "Because it's specified in the standard" a valid answer for you?

Comment: as i recall theres a special rule for member functions or something like that (but im not a language lawyer)

Comment: Specifically, the interior of a member function is a "complete-class context". So inside the body of that function, it has to be acting with a complete definition of the class. Classes are in fact more robust than syntactic sugar for free functions and automatic population of the first argument.

Comment: We can do it because the standard in effect places member function bodies *logically* after the class, and the standard does that because it is useful and convenient.

Comment: Some of the behavior is fallout from C lineage (as in the 2nd case), and some of the behavior is specified from the syntax and semantics introduced in C++'s novel behavior (well, "novel" as of 40 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

You can call a regular function without defining it first. You just need a declaration:

```
void caller() {
    void callee();
    callee();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your struct example is essentially rewritten by the compiler to only contain the *declarations* within the class, and the *definitions* outside. Since the call to the member function happens in the definition, by this point all the member functions have been declared and can be called.

```
struct A {
    void caller();
    void callee();
};

inline void A::caller() {
    callee();       // fine, because callee has been declared by this point
}

inline void A::callee() {
    std::cout << "callee" << std::endl;
}
```

There's no such rewriting with free (non-member) functions and so a declaration *must* be visible before the function is called.

Comment: Compiler also adds an `inline`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Well, the compiler makes sure it *behaves* as if it's inline, but that's a fair point. Edited, thanks.